# Basic TCP protocol questions -- What happens on send() and recv()

Tags: tcp

I have some basic questions on TCP protocol

**Situation**: Machine_A calls send(sockfd) to send data to Machine_B. send() call succeeds.

**Question**: When the send() call returns, does it mean the data has already reached Machine_B? Or has it just been accepted by the operating system

**Situation**: Machine_A calls send(sockfd) to send data to Machine_B. But the application_B on Machine_B has not been reading from the socket fast enough. Application_A is writing 10MB/s but Application_B is just reading 1KB/sec.

**Question**:

1. When does the send() call succeed on Machine_A in this case?
2. Does it succeed the moment the data is submitted to OS_A on Machine_A or does it wait until there is an acknowledgement from OS_B?
3. Does OS_B require Application_B to pull the packets before it is acknowledged to OS_A?

Comment: 1. It means all the data has been transferred to the local socket send buffer. 2. Yes; no. 3. No.

Answer (score 1):

`send` only cares about putting data into the local socket buffer, i.e. it will not wait for an ACK from the recipients machine or even wait until the data are processed by the recipient application (which is even later). If you need this kind of information you would need to have some application-level acknowledgement. Moreover, while an ACK gets send by TCP it would not get send by other protocols like UDP anyway.

`send` will only fail if it cannot put data in the socket buffer, maybe because there is no socket buffer (socket closed) or because the socket buffer is already full but `send` called non-blocking. If the socket buffer is full and `send` is called blocking it will just block until there is again space in the socket buffer.